# Evitar refresh de pagina al pulsar botones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos, estoy buscando la manera de evitar el refresh que hace mi pagina al agregar un elemento mediante la pulsación de un botón, ya sea sumarle, restarle o eliminar un elemento. Quisiera que se quede en el mismo sitio y no me refresque la pagina ya que me lleva al inicio y es incomodo. Mi código es el siguiente:

Estos son los botones que hacen las acciones:

```
 <a href="#"><img onclick="add(<?php echo $id ?>,'add');" src="img/sumar.png"></a>

 <a href="#"><img onclick="add(<?php echo $id ?>,'remove');" src="img/resta.png"></a>

 <a href="#"><img onclick="add(<?php echo $id ?>,'removeProd');" src="img/remove.png"></a>
```

Este es mi JS:

```
 function add(valor,valor2){
  $.get('add.php',{id:valor,action:valor2},function(data){
    $('.producto').html(data);
  })
 }

 function add2(valor,valor2){
  $.get('add.php',{id:valor,action:valor2},function(data){
   window.location='';
  })

 }

 function add3(valor,valor2,valor3){
   $.get('add.php',{id:valor,action:valor2,su:valor3},function(data){
        $('.producto').html(data);
   })
 }
```

Esto es lo que tengo, lo que quiero es que al presionar cualquiera de los botones no me recargue la pagina, ya que me lleva hasta la parte superior de la pagina de nuevo. A quien pueda ayudarme con esto muchas gracias, no conozco bien js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como está su código para evitar el `refresh` tendría que hacer al menos dos cambios , primero retornar `false` en sus funciones , y además añadir el `return` dentro del `onclick` antes de llamar a la función.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><img onclick="return add(<?php echo $id ?>,'add');" src="img/sumar.png"></a>
```

**Js** *(igual, return false a sus demás funciones)*

```
function add(valor,valor2){
  $.get('add.php',{id:valor,action:valor2},function(data){
    $('.producto').html(data);
  })
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Saludos Joel. Muchas gracias, a funcionado perfecto!

Comment: @Dev. Joel pregunta: ¿El codigo JS que reflejaria dentro de .producto? [Estoy buscando una solución a algo parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133915/cómo-hacer-que-se-agregen-productos-al-carrito-en-la-misma-pagina)

Comment: @Juan No entiendo su pregunta. ¿Es sobre mi respuesta ?

Comment: Si @Joel. Queria saber que hace en su ejemplo el $('.producto') y le deje link de mi problema que estoy resolviendo.

Comment: @Juan solo selecciona el elemento con la clase producto, solo me base en el ejemplo de Alejo. Saludos, si ya formulo su pregunta seguro ya recibirá respuestas para ella. Este no es el espacio adecuado. Saludos

Comment: @Joel Gracias por explicarlo. Mil disculpas no estaba al tanto. Saludos.